# How to Move decimal value from right to left?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display decimal value like 0.00 in calculator using javascript.
my problem is:

1. when I clicked 3 displays `0.03`
2. when I clicked 4 displays `0.030.04`

I need to replace the digits from right to left.

```js
//here is my code 
var input = document.querySelector('.screen'); 
var inputVal = input.innerHTML; 
var btnVal = this.innerHTML; 
var num = btnval/math.pow(10,2); 
input.innerHtml +=num;
```

Comment: In JS, when you read value from markup, its read as string. You will have to parse it to number. You can try `value = +value*10 + input
`

Comment: where is your code you tried?

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: If you need a value as it is, why are you dividing it by 100? `var num = btnval/math.pow(10,2);`

Comment: Don't add code in comments, you can update your question using [edit]

Comment: okay thank you @barbsan

Answer (score 0):

You messed up with the following -

- If you need a number as it is, please don't divide it by 100
- It looks like your numbers are coming like a string; if so, just add a `+` sign ***or*** parse it as a number before addition, so that it can take it as a number.
- If you need a number with 2 decimals, you could simply use `.fixed(2)` attribute in js.

So, your code will look like this -

```
var input = document.querySelector('.screen');
var inputVal = input.innerHTML;
var btnVal = this.innerHTML;
// var num = btnval/math.pow(10,2);          // removed this
var num = parseFloat(btnval).toFixed(2);     // formatted as a decimal
input.innerHtml = num;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushar but when i click 4 it displays 4.00 then i clicked 5 it displays 5.00 i need to display like 0.45

Comment: Do you want to add it or append it? Is it like so - You click on 1, 2, 3, 4; it will display - 0.1234? & so on...

Comment: i want to append it. as am using fixed(2) function. i wanted to display like when i click 1,2,3,4 it should display - 12.34